# Android: downloading files through In-App-Purchase

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am developing an app in which user can browse through images. There is an upgrade button. When user clicks the upgrade button I want to download some more images on the device to browse.

Where should I put those extra images for user to download?

Can I put those images in Google Play itself, so that I don't have to access any server?

**EDIT:**

In ios we can add .pkg file and we can put images, database in this .pkg file. When the user will upgrade the app, this .pkg file will be available on his/her device and we can access it there.

Can we achieve something like this in Android?

Comment: no you can't integrate any files with in app purchase. You can download files separately and only allow access when they choose iab, see : http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

Comment: @Blundell To achieve this, do I will have to upload files at my server?

Comment: no you upload to Google Play - that is what you where asking

Comment: @Blundell Should I upload the images to Google Play and download them from Google Play when they click upgrade button? If its Possible, then how to do this? How can I upload images to Google Play?

Comment: @NiteshKumar Do you have any updates on this?